# How to convert a dataframe column to list and values in the list to be enclosed with double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list column in dataframe as mentioned below.

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({'a':["a,b,c"]})
```

df:

```
a
0  a,b,c
```

```
df.a.astype(str).values.tolist()
```

`['a,b,c']`

But I want the output to be ["a","b","c"] in this format.
Can someone help me with the code.

Comment: `df.a.str.split(',')` ??

Comment: I dont want to split the values in the list, instead I need each element of the list to be enclosed in double quotes

Comment: how about `[i.split(',') for i in df.a]`

Comment: @DppriyaReddy, double quoted yet in a single string as a whole? like `'"a","b","c"'`?

Comment: Try this - df.a.apply(lambda x: str(x.split(',')))

Comment: @Chris  Yes Chris , but whole list has to be enclosed in square brackets like  ["a", "b","c"]

Comment: @anky_91 Its not working

Comment: @ sat Its working. Thanks Sat

Comment: @DppriyaReddy welcome

Comment: @DppriyaReddy if `apply()` is working `df['a']=[i.split(',') for i in df.a]` should also work and should be faster too

Comment: @DppriyaReddy only thing missing is converting to string, this should work - df['a']=[str(i.split(',')) for i in df.a]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will result in the desired output -

```
df.a.apply(lambda x: str(x.split(',')))
```

Output -

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

We split on comma and then convert every element to string.

Edit 1 :

This piece of code can also be used to get the same output -

```
df['a']=[str(i.split(',')) for i in df.a]
```

Comment: HI can you tell me how to get double quotes in place of single quotes